# Commutativity of isometry and offsetting operations

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Given a regular surface $A$, if one were to take the parallel surface i.e.$B = A+r\boldsymbol{n}$, where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is the unit normal to the surface $A$ and then isometrically deform the offset surface $B$ to a surface $C$, then would $C$ be isometric to the surface $E$ obtained by isometrically deforming $A$ to another surface $D$ and then taking the offset of $D$?

In other words, do the operations of offsetting and isometrically deforming commute with each other?

Comment: Have you tried starting with a piece of a flat plane? To what surfaces is it isometric?

Comment: @TedShifrin It is isometric to developable surfaces and cylindrical and conical ones. But in the case of zero Gaussian curvature, I think the two operations do commute with each other.But it looks unlikely for negatively curved surfaces.

Comment: Right. I misread. What if you locally deform a sphere to a non-umbilic surface of constant positive curvature? Then the parallel surfaces will have different Gaussian curvatures.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you. Your example is conclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Minding's theorem, two surfaces of the same Gaussian curvature are (locally) isometric. So consider the unit sphere and a non-umbilic surface of constant Gaussian curvature $1$. For example, take the parametrized surface
$$\mathbf x(u,v) = \big(f(u)\cos v, f(u)\sin v, g(u)\big),$$
with
$$f(u) = A\cos u,\  A>0, A\ne 1, \quad\text{and}\quad g(u) = \int_0^u\sqrt{1-A^2\sin^2t}\, dt.$$
(If $A>1$, the domain has to be appropriately restricted.)
The principal curvatures (see, e.g., p. 53 of [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/users/user317/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf)) are
$$k_1 = \frac{A\cos u}{\sqrt{1-A^2\sin^2u}} \quad\text{and}\quad k_2 = \frac1{k_1}.$$
Thus, the Gaussian curvature is still $1$, but the mean curvature $H=\frac{k_1+k_2}2$ is quite different from $1$.

Now the Gaussian curvature of the outward parallel surface at distance $r$ from the unit sphere is
$$\frac1{(1+r)^2}$$
and the Gaussian curvature of the non-spherical surface (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2569962/principal-directions-of-parallel-offset-surfaces/2569976#2569976)) is
$$\frac1{1+2rH + r^2},$$
which is different. (The formulas in that linked question are working with the inward-pointing normal.) Thus, the parallel surface of the non-spherical surface is not isometric to the parallel surface of the spherical surface.